# How to record repeatable data into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have in database tables like this

```
products
similar_products_product
similar_products_view
```

in Products

> keep record of main product

in similar_products_product

> keep record of custom products that you can assignment into main product later one

in similar_products_view

> keep record of assignment main product and their similar_products_product

Query to insert into similar_products_view

```
foreach ($data['similar_products'] as $cat_id => $key) {
            foreach ($key as $similar_product_id) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "similar_products_view SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', similar_product_id = '" . (int)$similar_product_id . "', category_id = '" . (int)$cat_id . "'");
            }
        }
```

than i end up with records like this

```
id    product_id    similar_product_id    category_id
1     10            2                     7
2     10            4                     7
3     10            5                     7
4     10            10                    7
5     10            12                    7
6     10            15                    6
7     10            24                    6
8     10            30                    6
```

what will be the better way to record this results ?
is it something like to be record whole thing for same product_id at one line  ?

```
id    product_id    similar_product_id    category_id
1     10            2,4,5,10,12,15        7,6
```

but should know with similar_product_id match category_id
the record also should be able for DELETE,UPDATE,SELECT by similar_product_id and category_id

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Maybe are you looking for Triggers

Comment: @paskl can be done better organization of this records ? something like to be record whole thing for same product_id at one line ?

Comment: Research the term "database normalization"

Comment: @paskl isnt what im looking for , i update the topic

Comment: @DanielGS dont think this will help me

Comment: Well, normalization tells you to never save multiple values in one column. (Like you proposed.)

Comment: @bobibobi Saving multiple values to a single column is against normalization. It makes it pretty hard to form search queries around the data, makes it harder to update values if they change, and is just a headache overall (even though it may seem easier and better up front)

Comment: Your first approach with multiple _rows_ is better than using a single row. Maybe you could edit your question with a bit more information about the purpose of the tables so that we can help. Sounds like you have a _many-to-many_ between `products` >> `similar_products_view` << `similar_products_product`. Is that right?

Comment: @waterloomatt yes if you add for one main product 20 similar_products i end up with 20 rows of record if i do same for 1000 main products i will end up with 20,000 rows

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ok i got that, so is better to leave the way is it cant do anything to optimize records?

Comment: 20,000 rows are diddlysquat for an RDBMS. They are designed to handle much, much larger datasets. On a side note, just make sure that you actually need that `n-m` relationship. Maybe the `1-m` is all you need. Cheers.

Comment: @waterloomatt i didnt get only that 1-m , what you mean ?